# AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '<locals>.<lambda>'

Tags: python, python-3.6, pickle, python-3.7, jsonpickle

I am trying to pickle a nested dictionary which is created using:

```
collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
```

My simplified code goes like this:

```
class A:
  def funA(self):
    #create a dictionary and fill with values
    dictionary = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
    ...
    #then pickle to save it
    pickle.dump(dictionary, f)
```

However it gives error:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'A.funA.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

After I print dictionary it shows:

```
defaultdict(<function A.funA.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd569dd07b8> {...}
```

I try to make the dictionary global within that function but the error is the same.
I appreciate any solution or insight to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: cast your defaultdict to dict and it should hopefully work

Comment: You probably don't need a `lambda`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679806/attributeerror-cant-pickle-local-object-pre-datasets-locals-lambda-when and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70608810/pytorch-cant-pickle-lambda.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`pickle` records references to functions (module and function name), not the functions themselves. When unpickling, it will load the module and get the function by name. `lambda` creates anonymous function objects that don't have names and can't be found by the loader. The solution is to switch to a named function.

```
def create_int_defaultdict():
    return collections.defaultdict(int)

class A:
  def funA(self):
    #create a dictionary and fill with values
    dictionary = collections.defaultdict(create_int_defaultdict)
    ...
    #then pickle to save it
    pickle.dump(dictionary, f)
```

Answer (score 5):

As @tdlaney explained, `lambda` creates an anonymous function which can't be pickled. The most concise solution is to replace `lambda` with `partial` (no new function needed):

```py
from functools import partial

class A:
  def funA(self):
    #create a dictionary and fill with values
    dictionary = collections.defaultdict(partial(collections.defaultdict, int))
    ...
    #then pickle to save it
    pickle.dump(dictionary, f)
```